# L.Control.Search - How can I sort the results list in alphanumeric order?

Tags: javascript, sorting, leaflet, geojson

I am creating a web visor through Leaflet. I have included a geojson layer which is composed of two fields ('id', and 'centro_mando').

I have used L.Control.Search for searching the results in to the 'centro_mando' field. It works propertly, but the results that the program offers to my user are not in alphabetic order.

I would like to get those results in alphabetical order. Is there any way to achieve it?

[image]

It is my code:

```
/* add options to control*/

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
      layer: cmJS,
      propertyName: 'centro_man',
      autoType: false,
      textErr: 'Cm not found',
      zoom: 18,
      marker: false,
      circleLocation: false
  });

  /* add control to map*/
 
 map.addControl(searchControl);
```